# Post value using h:inputtext and a4j:support onkeyup

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I was originally posting a value in the h:inputText field with an a4j:commandButton but I had to change the commandButton to s:link because the commandButton is also triggering a pdf document to be exported, and I believe that with an ajax call, the doc is rendered on the browser instead.

So now I am trying to post the value using h:inputText and a4j:support

```
<h:inputText id="numberOfPatients" 
    value="#{printLabelsReqFormsAction.numberOfPatients}">
    <a4j:support event="onkeyup" 
        action="#{printLabelsReqFormsAction.setNumberOfPatients(numberOfPatients)}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

(sorry for the weird formatting..)

My setNumberOfPatients(x) is getting called but I don't think I am passing the value correctly. How should I pass the value of the h:inputText field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly set the value of `numberOfPatients` while executing ajax support. `a4j:support` tag processes its parent component during its execution, meaning the value for `numberOfPatients` will be set for each `onkeyup` event, even you don't invoke an `action` event. You can see it better at [Richfaces' site](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#DataProcessingOptions):

> RichFaces uses form based approach for Ajax request sending. This means each time, when you click an Ajax button or  produces an asynchronous request, the data from the closest JSF form is submitted with the XMLHTTPRequest object. The form data contains the values from the form input element and auxiliary information such as state saving data.
>
> When "ajaxSingle" attribute value is "true" , it orders to include only a value of the current component (along with  or `<a4j:actionparam>` values if any) to the request map. In case of `<a4j:support>` , it is a value of the parent component. An example is placed below:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{person.name}">
        <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="test" ajaxSingle="true"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{person.middleName}"/>
</form>
```

In other words, for your case this should work:

```
<h:inputText id="numberOfPatients" 
    value="#{printLabelsReqFormsAction.numberOfPatients}">
    <a4j:support event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Specify an action method only if you want to add extra logic when the event happens.

Comment: So I am debugging with this suggested code and see that numberOfPatients is being set to my input value in the text box. But when I click on the s:link button I've created below, the set method is being called again and resetting to 0. It seems like what you've suggested is correct but I probably need to do something else with this link

Comment: That's the expected behaviour for `request scoped` managed bean. Take into account that you're generating another request when you make the ajax call and the bean is set to live only for a request. Which JSF version are you using? In JSF 2 you can use `view scope` to make the bean live longer, but JSF 1.x will force you to preserve in some way the value you set, using a session attribute, for example, as `view scope` is not implemented there. Other choice would be to make the entire bean `session scoped`.

Comment: I am using JSF 1.1 so I guess things just got a bit more complicated. I will look into preserving the value but it looks like I'm on track! Thanks for the detailed explanation of everything, I am learning all of this on-the-go

Comment: Thanks again, I made my bean session scoped and everything i working very well.

Comment: @jackie please do not use session scope for your bean, instead change it to request scope and use the `@KeepAlive` annotation in your bean to keep your request scoped bean alive while the user is still in the same view.

Comment: Ok I will try that now